# В очереди проверок пустая правка засчитывается как проверка

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, очередь-проверок

В очереди проверок «Сообщения низкого качества» можно осуществить «пустую» правку сообщения. То есть нажать «Править» и сразу подтвердить правку, не внося измененй. Система засчитывает это за осуществлённую проверку.

Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/42177. В примере можно открыть вопрос и убедиться, что моих правок в истории вопроса нет.

Такая правка не должна считаться прохождением проверки. Возможно, она позволяет и метапроверку (ловушку, аудит) пройти.

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, при попытке улучшить автозаванделенный пост аудит провалится. Аудитов в другую сторону не встречал.

Comment: @Discord: а если отклонить и редактировать?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Скорее всего, аудит не будет провален. Но осмотреть глазами текст быстрее, чем ходить по страницам, поэтому вряд ли такая стратегия будет интересна робо-ревьюерам.

Comment: @Discord: вы продумываете стратегию роборевьюера, чтобы потом её блокировать?

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Что и как я могу блокировать?

Comment: @Discord: если я правильно понял, вы оцениваете уязвимости в системе очереди проверок относительно того, могут ли их эксплуатировать умные роборевьюеры.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: а блокировать можно только тем, что поднимать вопрос на Мете, чтобы разработчики закрывали эксплоиты.

Comment: В данном случае я просто вслух прикинул, насколько верно ваше опасение. / Запросы по улучшению аудитов давно висят, ещё бы ими занимались... Скажем, есть предложение делать аудиты правок **с** `развешиванием` *случайного* `форматирования`, и от них было бы больше пользы, чем от попыток перехитрить хитрых ревьюеров. Защиту аудитов со временем наоборот снизили.

Comment: @Discord: кстати, про случайное форматирование точно надо продвинуть идею. Это как раз наш случай.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, вы не до конца понимаете цели аудита.

1. Одно из отличий робо-проверок от полезных состоит в том, что на них было потрачено слишком мало времени. Меньше, чем ушло бы на загрузку формы правки или страницы самого вопроса.
2. Сам процесс проверки довольно скучен и, чтобы проверяющие на засыпали в процессе, им время от времени подкидывают "глупые" вопросы, над которыми они могут посмеяться или поразмышлять

**Дополнение**: Я хочу сказать, что действовать по правилам тут уже выгоднее, чем пытаться обойти "ловушки". Поэтому защиту аудитов и не укрепляют

Comment: Посмотрел в статистику по проверке «первых сообщений». У самого «быстрого участника» проверка занимает в среднем 15 секунд. За такое время страница, конечно, грузится полностью. А проблема с этим участником в том, что он почти всегда (88%) жмет «ничего делать не надо» — даже когда вопрос с плохим форматированием или вообще оффтопик.

Comment: Голосует за вопрос в 3% случаев, комментарий оставляет в 0% (никогда). Вот примерно это называют робо-проверкой. Новичкам почти никакой пользы от таких проверок. А очередь именно для того работает, чтобы новички получали помощь от более опытных участников.

Comment: Но вы правы, на робо-проверки действительно тратится слишком мало времени, чтобы успеть что-то полезное сделать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, самая быстрая проверка - это "о! я же только что видел этот вопрос в соседней очереди, с ним всё хорошо" и оп, а кнопка-то задисейблена, надо подождать, пока разблокируется.