# Поздравление об успешной проверке после нажатия на "Улучшить"/"Править"

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, очередь-проверок, аудит

В очереди правок попалась проверка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/285686

Я нажал "Улучшить" и сразу получил сообщение "Вы прошли проверку".

В очереди на закрытие попалась такая проверка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/285687

После нажатия на "Править" получил сообщение "Вы прошли проверку".

Так и задумано? Я могу себя обезопасить навсегда от аудита таким образом.

Comment: Уточните, ***каким*** образом вы планируете обезопасить себя от аудита навсегда - всегда нажимать правку и дальше ..что?

Comment: [meta-tag:так-задумано]

Comment: @Kromster всегда успех будет )

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1770/218976

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То что проверку легко обойти - не секрет. Достаточно открыть вопрос/ответ в другой вкладке и посмотреть закрыт он или удален, или открыт и заплюсован.

Идентичны ли с точки зрения системы проверок получение голоса за (не)удаление и попытка исправить - думаю да. И то и то означает, что вы достаточно внимательны к очереди и наводите порядок.

Итого, видя как легко обойти "проверку внимательности", имхо, особой проблемы нет.